# What is the exact meaning of the phrase "from the top on down"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across the phrase "from the top on down" in this sentence,

> England is rotting **from the top on down**! We pledge our revenge on Nottingham Town!

I consulted some dictionaries but could only find "from top to bottom" and "from the top-down". Does the phrase "from the top on down" have the same meaning as "from top to bottom" or the same meaning as "from the top-down"?

Comment: _From the top on down_ is identical in meaning to _from top to bottom_ and _from the top-down_. "On" was added to _from the top down_ so that the two sentences in the chant will have the same number of syllables: to suit the _meter._

Comment: @P. E. Dant  But I can't find "from the top down" in any dictionary.

Comment: The hyphen in _from the top-down_ is unimportant. It's the same phrase. They all mean exactly the same thing. And _from the top down_ is in Cambridge, Merriam Webster, and the OED, at minimum.

Answer (score 3):

Your quote by the "Merry Men" in [*The Adventures of Robin Hood* (Scene 2)](http://www.burbank.k12.il.us/userfiles/203/Classes/756//userfiles/203/my%20files/the%20legend%20of%20robin%20hood%20-%20print.pdf?id=22495)

> **from the top on down**
>
> England is rotting **from the top on down**! We pledge our revenge on Nottingham Town!

has the same meaning as

> from head to toe
>   from head to tail
>   from tip to toe
>   from top to bottom

meaning the entire *structure* or *being*.

**NB**: One also notes that "**bottom**" does not rhyme very well with "**town**", and by phrasing this way the rhythm is kept consistent.

I originally thought this might have been a Leicester City football chant, but *Nottingham City FC* is commonly known as ***Forest***.

Answer (score 0):

'Top-down' and 'bottom-up' as adjectives imply a directionality.

In the workplace, we might say some project is planned from the 'top-down' as meaning the same as "dictated from higher levels of management" or "centrally controlled", whereas a project planned 'bottom-up' is the same as "designed/planned by the users or lower-level employees" or the like.

You see similar language in newspaper discussions of political parties, e.g. "The party is neglecting its grassroots by rigging the primary in favor of Candidate X, and leading from the top down is sure to breed resentment." etc.

This particular passage is from Robin Hood, and in this context what they are saying is the system is corrupt, starting at the top (the King) and down through his agents (in this case the Sheriff of Nottingham).

Comment: This does not really address the question which is about the phrase _from top on down_ and not about _top-down_.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/128176)